# How to check for specific backend error keys when using async/await?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display a custom message in Vue (with Django as the backend) when creating an account if the entered email already exists in the database.

Currently the server returns a 400 with the following response:
`{"email":["There is another user with this email"]}`

How can I access this error object to check if it contains an "email" key?

I've found this approach creating a wrapper: https://dev.to/sadarshannaiynar/capture-error-and-data-in-async-await-without-try-catch-1no2
but I feel like there must be a better/simpler way of handling this

Things I tried:

1) `const { error, data } = await usersAPI.create(userData)`
where "create" is:

`create (data) {
    return Vue.axios.post(url, data, config)
  }`
then `console.error(error)` (but it doesn't print anything)

2) Using `try-catch(error)` - prints nothing

3) Appending `catch(e => console.error(e)` to the await call - still nothing

Comment: did you try to wrap request with try catch?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. I'm going to update the question, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Axios return an object error, you can get the content with `error.message`.

```js
axios.post('/badurl')
.then(response => { 
 console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This displays `Request failed with status code 400`, but I still cannot access the server's response object